# Working with Decimal fields in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2008 w/SP2.

I've got an incoming decimal(9,2) field incoming through my **OLE DB transformation** to my **recordset destination transformation**.  And I see that when I click on the Input and Output properties tab of the destination Transformation, it's showing this particular field as type DT_NUMERIC for some reason. It's like it's reading it as something other than a decimal? I don't know..I'm not an SSIS guru.

So continuing on...the problem I have starts here with me trying to stuff the value into a variable for this decimal field. In a **foreach loop**, I have a **variable** to represent this decimal field so I can work with it.

The first problem that I believe is pretty well known is *SSIS variables do not have a decimal type*.  And from my own testing and what I've read out there, people are using type **object** for the variable to make SSIS "happy" with decimal values?  It makes mine happy.

But, then in my foreach loop, I have **a for loop**.  And inside that I'm using an E**xecute SQL Task transformation**.  In it, I need to **create a parameter mapping** to my **variable** so I can work with that decimal field in my T-SQL call in here.  So now I see a type decimal for the parameter and use it and set that to point to my variable.

*When I run SSIS and it hits my SQL call, I get this in my output window.*:

```
   The type is not supported.DBTYPE_DECIMAL
```

So I am hitting a wall here.  All I wanna do is work with a decimal!!!

Comment: I have the same complaing!, I just want to work with a decimal!!!.... its that so much to ask? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try either converting the value to a double or a varchar in your data flow task rather than an object. Note that you may have to use a cast or convert statement in your execute sql task to change the type back to decimal in your transact sql statement.

Comment: I've tried both in my variable...both types and it does not like varchar, SSIS will complain.  Same with Double, it gives me a compile error due to mismatch of types.  And what do you mean by in my data flow task?  It comes in my OLE DB transformation to my recordset destination.  Where in there are you proposing I can specify the type?  It determines it for me.

Comment: "Note that you may have to use a cast or convert statement in your execute sql task".  The problem is I can't even get to that point.  If I for example specify my variable holding this field as an object, then in my SQL Task, make it a decimal or something else, I get a runtime error.

Comment: I'm gonna post print screens, that should help so you can see exactly what I have so far...give me a sec.

Comment: I even just tried a data conversion on that one field after my OLE DB connector and forced it to be Decimal in my recordset before processing it in my foreach and still, in my SQL Task, after setting it to decimal I get Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "INSERT INTO ..." failed with the following error: "The type is not supported.DBTYPE_DECIMAL".

Comment: So try casting it to a DT_STR in the data flow and mapping it a string SSIS variable. Then in your execute SQL task, map it to a parameter type varchar. Wherever you have your transact sql code block stored, add additional cast logic to convert it from varchar to decimal as needed.

Comment: I'm not converting the field to object or varchar.  I said I'm stuffing it into a varible and the types are object, char, etc. for a variable.  There is no varchar for a variable's type and if I try to make it double I get "User::AvgWt" differs from the current variable type.

Comment: the only other thing I can think to provide at this point is my data flow which is brining the record set into my recordset transformation is getting the data from calling a view.  In the view, it's returning that decimal field like this: CAST(SalesGrade.Weight / SalesGrade.Head AS Decimal(9, 2)) AS AvgWt

Comment: this is a true pain in the ass.

Comment: "So try casting it to a DT_STR in the data flow and mapping it a string SSIS variable"  ok what var type??  I've tried so many combinations it makes me wanna throw my laptop against the wall with SSIS, what a nightmare.

Comment: I basically tried yours Tolowe.  It doesn't convert it to decimal...when it inserts back into the DB, I get the value but it strips out the precision (the 2 decimal places) for some reason.

Comment: your solution kinda helped, last thing is I lost my precision...the 2 decimal places when it converted to string and back.  I did cast as decimal like this:  cast(theField as Decimal(9,2)) whereas theField was type string in my sql task (parameter) but somewhere in the translation whether when it was converted to string during my import the the recordset (where I used a Data Conversion transformation to convert it to a string) or whether when it was stuffed into a variable for my foreach, it lost the .00 at the end of the number.  So gotta figure out how to fix that in the process..not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue, and for my solution I used decimal to Int converter.

Comment: Some code? Some images?