# Decimal parameter error in Execute SQL TASK in SSIS 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am working on SSIS 2014. I need to pass a decimal parameter in SQL Execute task in SSIS. Getting the below error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query  failed with the following error: "The type is not supported.DBTYPE_DECIMAL".

I tried searching online but couldn't get the solution. Did anyone have this type of issue. I cannot change the datatype of the parameter it should be decimal only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452727/working-with-decimal-fields-in-ssis

Comment: checked that link is there any other way without converting it from decimal and since it is 2008 and I am working on 2014 do we have any other solution for this